# WPF Button Background when IsEnabled = False

Tags: wpf, button, styles

I try to set a style for my button when it is not enabled so that the Background LinearGradientBrush is similar to the one set for the button when it is enabled. I have tried with Triggers but it seems that only the text Color is changing:

```
<Application x:Class="RSPolar.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--Windows style-->
        <Style TargetType="Window">

            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush  StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.92" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.9" />
                        <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0.88" />
                        <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <!--Buttons style-->
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="48" Foreground="#00FF00" Text="{Binding Path=Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                            <TextBlock.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="1" Color="DarkGray" ShadowDepth="1" Direction="120"/>
                            </TextBlock.Effect>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush  StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.52" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.5" />
                        <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0.48" />
                        <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="5" BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.5" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <BlurEffect Radius="1"></BlurEffect>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FF0000" Text="{Binding Path=Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                                    <TextBlock.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="1" Color="DarkGray" ShadowDepth="1" Direction="120"/>
                                    </TextBlock.Effect>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush  StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1" />
                                <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.52" />
                                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.5" />
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0.48" />
                                <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="0" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: What exactly you want? do you want to have different background for enable and disable states of the button? As per the style you have created for the button, for both enable and disable state, button background is same. Only the ContentTemplate is different that's why text color is getting changed. If you want to change the background when button gets disable, give a different background in the trigger.

Comment: And thats what I did. At the end of the code is the new Background Color (the same in this Moment) but the Background is the Default Background for unactive Buttons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not be defining the `ContentTemplate` property. If you want to change what the button looks like, you should define the `Template` property and add your `Trigger`s into the `ControlTemplate` you define there instead.

Perhaps it would help if you read the [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Creating a ControlTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN? You can also find an example of using `ControlTemplate.Triggers` in the [`ControlTemplate` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

However, here is a simple example:

In `Resources`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExampleButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border Background="LightGreen" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" 
        CornerRadius="5" x:Name="Border" Padding="10">
        <ContentPresenter />    
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In XAML page:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Template="{StaticResource ExampleButton}" Content="Click me" />
    <Button Template="{StaticResource ExampleButton}" Content="Click me" 
        IsEnabled="False" />
</StackPanel>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You just need to substitute the 'plain' `Background` value for your `LinearGradientBrush` as you have in *your* example:

In `Resources`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExampleButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" 
        CornerRadius="5" x:Name="Border" Padding="10">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush  StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1" />
                <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.52" />
                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0.48" />
                <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <ContentPresenter />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush  StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.52" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.5" />
                        <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0.48" />
                        <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

> Why is Target Border setting the color of the Background of the button? Shouldn't it change the color of the border?

The `Background` of the `Button` *is* the `Background` of the `Border`.

Comment: The example works but I am still not able to do what I try: have a gradient in both states from IsEnabled. With your example I can create a "plane" background in the same color, but no gradient.
Why is Target Border setting the color of the Background of the button? Shouldn't it change the color of the border?

Comment: As I said, I provided *a simple example*. You should be able to replace the `Background` value above with your own one... the gradient from *your* example.